# Kaggle cereal data set - Rating seems to be a function of other predictors?

Tags: regression

I'm doing a project in linear regression and I found the Kaggle cereal data set:

https://www.kaggle.com/crawford/80-cereals

I did some regressions and, unless I made a big mistake somewhere, it looks like the rating field is a function of a few other predictors. Here is the regression equation I came up with. Notice that all of the predictors have very low p-values and the R^2 is close enough to 1 that R just shows 1. Is this an indicator that the rating is just a function of these other predictors?

```
##  
## Call: 
## lm(formula = rating ~ calories + carbo + fat + fiber + potass +  
##     protein + sodium + sugars + vitamins, data = cereal, na.action = na.omit) 
##  
## Residuals: 
##            Min             1Q         Median             3Q            Max  
## -0.00000053429 -0.00000025369  0.00000003961  0.00000024239  0.00000055130  
##  
## Coefficients: 
##                    Estimate      Std. Error    t value            Pr(>|t|) 
## (Intercept) 54.927184128972  0.000000279443  196559702 <0.0000000000000002 
## calories    -0.222724169867  0.000000007501  -29694282 <0.0000000000000002 
## carbo        1.092450964974  0.000000034917   31287364 <0.0000000000000002 
## fat         -1.691407949221  0.000000081015  -20877762 <0.0000000000000002 
## fiber        3.443479791684  0.000000047562   72399805 <0.0000000000000002 
## potass      -0.033993351797  0.000000001601  -21228850 <0.0000000000000002 
## protein      3.273173885524  0.000000055510   58964906 <0.0000000000000002 
## sodium      -0.054492702212  0.000000000491 -110974232 <0.0000000000000002 
## sugars      -0.724895121249  0.000000033108  -21895192 <0.0000000000000002 
## vitamins    -0.051211969530  0.000000001779  -28778552 <0.0000000000000002 
##                 
## (Intercept) *** 
## calories    *** 
## carbo       *** 
## fat         *** 
## fiber       *** 
## potass      *** 
## protein     *** 
## sodium      *** 
## sugars      *** 
## vitamins    *** 
## --- 
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 
##  
## Residual standard error: 0.0000003069 on 64 degrees of freedom 
##   (3 observations deleted due to missingness) 
## Multiple R-squared:      1,  Adjusted R-squared:      1  
## F-statistic: 1.696e+16 on 9 and 64 DF,  p-value: < 0.00000000000000022
```

UPDATE: For what it's worth, I tried doing a residual plot:

```
residuals = summary(model)$residuals
residual_model <- lm(residuals ~ cereal$rating)

plot(cereal$rating, residuals)
abline(residual_model, col="black")
```

[image: residual plot for my linear regression model]

Comment: Have you done any exploratory analysis of the predictor variables? Have you tried doing any diagnostics of the fitted model?

Comment: @vigos I'm a student and our textbook doesn't go into exploratory analysis or diagnostistics. Any links to new methods to try would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: well most likely your model is overfitting the data. You could read this as a start https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/r-squared-too-high/ also you could look at the other kernels on kaggle and filter by R. Also maybe start with some basic  tutorials as well https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/linear-regression-R

Comment: Maybe?  They aren't exactly forthcoming about what the rating is or where it comes from.

Comment: @vigos Is there any test I can do to check if I am overfitting?

Comment: Your output already suggests to us that this is over-fitted but without knowing what the rating is and how it was arrived at it is difficult to know what to suggest next.

Comment: If your text doesn't go into exploratory analysis or diagnostics, then you need a new text. One good text at a fairly introductory level is Regression Analysis by Example. But, really, any good book on regression will cover these things. You could also try Statistics by Pisani and Purves.

Comment: There is guaranteed collinearity. Calories is computed by looking at fat, carbs and protein.  I think the formula is cal  = 3.5C + 3.5P + 7F but I'm not sure of the exact numbers. In any case, you can't include all four of those variables. There is likely other collinearity as well - carbs are going to be very related to sugars, for instance.